# Understanding a proof that if $p\mid x^2 + y^2$, $gcd(x,y)=1$, then $p$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ for some possibly different $x,y$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading a proof of the following proposition (quoted from D.Cox's *Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$*, claimed to originate from Euler):

> If $p\mid x^2 + y^2$, $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $p$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$ for some possibly different $x,y$.

It's first step assets that

> Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $N = a^2 + b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. If $a$ and $b$ are changed by multiples of $p$, we still have $p\mid a^2 + b^2$. We may thus assume that $\vert a\vert < p/2$ and $\vert b\vert < p/2$, which in turn implies that $N<p^2/2$.

I do not understand how may one "change by multiples of $p$" $a$ and $b$ so that $|a| \lt p/2$ and $|b|\lt p/2$, for example in the case $p=5, a=3,b=4$? Can anyone clarify it for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any relatively prime $a$ and $b$ where, for some odd prime $p$, we have $p \mid a^2+b^2$, we then also have $a = c_{1}p+r_{1}, \;\; 0 \lt r_{1} \lt p$ and $b = c_{2}p+r_{2}, \;\; 0 \lt r_{2} \lt p$. With $a_1 = a - c_{1}p = r_{1}$ and $b_1 = b - c_{2}p = r_{2}$, we have $p \mid a_1^{2}+b_1^{2}$. Then, for example, if $a_1 \gt \frac{p}{2}$, we can instead use $a_{2} = r_{1} - p$, where now $\lvert a_{2}\rvert \lt \frac{p}{2}$. We can also handle $b_1$ similarly.

With your specific example of $p = 5$, we can replace $a = 3$ with $a_1 = 3 - 5 = -2$, and $b = 4$ with $b_1 = 4 - 5 = -1$.

Comment: Thank you. My fault is that I misinterpreted "changed by multiples" as "$\frac{a}{c_1 p}$" for some $c_1$.